# Display records from table1 and records from table2 which does not exist in table 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've two table which contains three property in each. I want to display all records from `table 1` and in `table 2` extract only the records which do not exist in `table 1`.

table 1

```
  ID   Percentage  OrderDate
+----+------------+----------+
  1      2.0       2015-05-08
  1      5.0       2014-05-08 
  1      19.65     2013-05-08
  1      5.06      2012-05-08
  1      98.0      2011-05-08
  1      8.56      2010-05-08
+----+------------+----------+
```

table 2

```
  ID   Percentage  OrderDate
+----+------------+----------+
  1      45.5      2015-05-08
  1      45.23     2014-05-08 
  1      12.00     2013-05-08
  1      6.45      2012-05-08
  1      18.0      2011-05-08
  1      5.2       2010-05-08
  1      12.0      2009-05-08
  1      22.78     2008-05-08 
  1      48.9      2007-05-08
  1      7.89      2006-05-08
  1      17.96     2005-05-08
  1      11.3      2004-05-08
+----+------------+----------+
```

Comment: Show your query that you have tried? Also, they are called columns.

Comment: don't forget alway accept one answer, the one who helped more!

Comment: perfect i will do that but sometimes i really forget

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`EXCEPT` keyword](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/except.php):

```
SELECT ID, Pourcentage, OrderDate
FROM table1
UNION
(
    SELECT ID, Pourcentage, OrderDate
    FROM table2
    EXCEPT
    SELECT ID, Pourcentage, OrderDate
    FROM table1
)
```

Comment: could we use except in sql server , i did not know that

Comment: Yep, introduced with SQL 2008 I believe.

Comment: i want to make a query which display all the rows from the table 1 and the rows doesnot exist from table 2

Comment: `UNION` by itself removes duplicates.

Comment: As in insert the missing records to table1? Or just display them?

Comment: just display them

Comment: That should do it then. If you want two record sets, just remove the union & the parentheses. Then the first set shows all of table1 and the second result set will show records in table2 that don't exist in table1.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which columns your are comparing you could use something like below.

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Percentage, t1.OrderDate
FROM table1 t1
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.ID, t2.Percentage, t2.OrderDate
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.ID <> t1.ID AND t2.Percentage <> t1.Percentage AND t2.OrderDate <> t1.OrderDate
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want remove duplicate  use union

```
 select ID, Percentage, OrderDate
 from table1
 union
 select ID, Percentage, OrderDate
 from table2
```

if you want all the rows from both the table use union all

```
 select ID, Percentage, OrderDate
 from table1
 union all
 select ID, Percentage, OrderDate
 from table2
```